# Dynamically create an array for Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have to call an asynchronous function multiple times (but the number of calls is dynamic).  For some reason, using this approach for the `Promise.all()` the functions in the array `getPricesCalls` don't actually fire.

```
var getPrice = function (exchange, product) {
    var priceData = {};
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (exchange == 'GDAX') {
            const gdaxPublicClient = new Gdax.PublicClient(product);
            gdaxPublicClient.getProductTicker((error, response, data) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(Error(error));
                } else {
                    console.log("GDAX ", product, ": ", data['price']);
                    priceData[exchange] = {
                        product: parseFloat(data['price'])
                    }
                    resolve(priceData);
                }
            });
        }

        if (exchange == 'POLONIEX') {
            poloniex.returnTicker(function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(Error(error));
                } else {
                    console.log("POLONIEX ", product, ": ", data[product]['last']);
                    priceData[exchange] = {
                        product: parseFloat(data[product]['last'])
                    }
                    resolve(priceData);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

var exchanges = ['GDAX', 'POLONIEX'];
var gdaxProducts = ['BTC-USD', 'ETH-BTC', 'LTC-BTC'];
var poloniexProducts = ['USDT_BTC', 'BTC_ETH', 'BTC_LTC'];
var products = {
    "GDAX": gdaxProducts,
    "POLONIEX": poloniexProducts
}
var gdaxPrices = {};
var poloPrices = {};

var getPricesCalls = [];
for (var exch in exchanges) {
    for (var product in products) {
        var functionCall = getPrice(exch, product);
        getPricesCalls.push(functionCall);
    }
}

// Manually creating the array works:
// var getPricesCalls = [getPrice(exchanges[0], gdaxProducts[0]), getPrice(exchanges[1], poloniexProducts[1])];

Promise.all(getPricesCalls).then(function (results) {
    console.log(results);
}, function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: You're passing `"0"` instead of `"GDAX"` and `"1"` instead of `"POLONIEX"` (and similarly for the products). See the linked question's answers for why. I suggest the first step when you run into something like this that isn't working should be to step through the code with a debugger; there's almost certainly one built into your IDE, one built into Node (using Chrome/Chromium as its UI), and one built into all major browsers.

Comment: Thanks to @T.J. Crowder I was able to create the array using a .forEach loop over the gdaxProducts and poloniexProducts arrays:

    var getPricesCalls = [];
    for (var exch in products) {
        products[exch].forEach(function(product) {
            var functionCall = getPrice(exch, product);
            getPricesCalls.push(functionCall);
        })
    }